# Send Mailing StringBuilder Stuck

Tags: asp.net

I declared StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(); and I wrote some string with  builder.AppendLine("xyz");

Mailing process was executed successfully.But When I try to write some information with builder.AppendLine("xyz"); Mail content always return empty :(.

How can I fill my mail content with builder.AppendLine("xyz");

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this if the email needs to be in HTML format.

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

hw.Write("xyz");
```

Comment: I want to fill mail context.When I sent my mail to me ,I should see some info about my customer with  builder.AppendLine("User Name = " + txtName.Text); in my mail

Comment: Do you have some sample code for the mailing process you could put up?